# "Protocols cannot be used with isinstance()" - why not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, isinstance

The new `typing` module contains several objects with names like "SupportsInt" (-Float, -Bytes, etc.). The name, and the descriptions on [the documentation page for the module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), might be read to suggest that you can test whether an object is of a type that "supports `__int__()`". But if you try to use `isinstance()`, it gives a response that makes it clear that that isn't something you are meant to do:

```
>>> isinstance(5, typing.SupportsInt)
(Traceback omitted)
TypeError: Protocols cannot be used with isinstance().
```

On the other hand, you can use `issubclass()`:

```
>>> issubclass((5).__class__, typing.SupportsInt)
True
>>> issubclass(type(5), typing.SupportsInt)
True
```

What is a "protocol" in this context? Why does it disallow the use of `isinstance()` in this way?

Comment: The purpose of the `typing` module is **not** to provide a way to perform those checks. It's meant to provide a common way to provide the types of functions etc. in their annotations. Duck-typing is still preferred, you can use those types to tell your user how the function is intended to be called.

Comment: @Bakuriu, but the typing module is provided in part to allow static type-checking, and so it is reasonable to suppose that it will provide the machinery for identifying (say) whether a particular object is of a particular type. If I invoke a function passing 5 as a parameter that is annotated as being of type typing.SupportsInt, then how will a static type checker know that this is valid?

Comment: Not to mention that runtime checking is essential if we're trying to dynamically load something from details in a configuration file, and we need to check that what we loaded does in fact conform to the expected protocol.

Answer (score 11):

If you reached this question wanting to get around the error (like I did), the solution is to decorate the protocol class with [`@runtime_checkable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.runtime_checkable):

```py
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable

@runtime_checkable
class StorageProtocol(Protocol):
    ...
```

> `@typing.`**`runtime_checkable`**
>
> Mark a protocol class as a runtime protocol.
>
> Such a protocol can be used with [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) and [`issubclass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass).

```py
storage = ...  # get something that must implement StorageProtocol
if not isinstance(storage, StorageProtocol):
    raise RuntimeError(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says: `At runtime, isinstance(x, T) will raise TypeError. In general, isinstance() and issubclass() should not be used with types.` ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#typing.TypeVar )

Comment: This is a description of what happens. The question asks why this is the behaviour. You have answered a different question to the one that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

This is all of the reasoning given in `PEP 484`, the PEP for the `typing` module:

> Because typing.Callable does double-duty as a replacement for collections.abc.Callable , isinstance(x, typing.Callable) is implemented by deferring to `isinstance(x, collections.abc.Callable) . However, isinstance(x, typing.Callable[...]) is not supported.

A protocol is also known as a `magic method`. These are most of the python protocols (full list [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames)):

```
>>> dir(object)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__',
'__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', 
'__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', 
'__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

I have not found any clear reason for why `typing` does not support `isinstance`. The reason that `issubclass` works is that `isinstance` uses the `__class_` protocol which is not allowed in `typing`, while `issubclass` uses the `__subclasshook__` protocol which is allowed. I believe the reason is that the functionality was already coded in `collections.abc.Callable` and they did not want to recode it in the `typing` module.

Answer (score 0):

Protocols are intended to be used together with static type checking, to illustrate that a method can use anything that satisfies the protocol, so that duck typing can be statically checked.

It intentionally does not add any kind of runtime behaviour. Using protocols should strictly decrease the amount of implicit branching in your code instead of increasing it. You can inherit from a protocol, but that's just to get warnings if you don't implement methods.